# Почему свойство Text в xaml не меняет данные в Design XAML страницы?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Почему данный код -

```
<ComboBox x:Name="roomSelect" Text="Список должностей" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,360,0,-283" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" FontSize="16" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Или этот -

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dataPiker" Text="Выберете  дату" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,214,0,-136" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" FontSize="16" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

не как не меняет текст в design страницы? В comboBox пусто, а в dataPiker стандартный Select a date.

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox` не может содержать произвольный текст в нередактируемом режиме. Он может содержать только один из элементов, заданных через `Items`/`ItemsSource`

Вы можете перевести его в редактируемый режим, установив `IsEditable="True"`, но, скорее всего, это вам не подойдет. Вам придется править шаблон `ComboBox` или размещать поверх него `TextBlock`. Примеры можно посмотреть здесь: [How to display default text “--Select Team --” in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1426050/6766879)

`DatePicker` может содержать в свойстве `Text` только валидную дату, если дата не парсится, то он выводит стандартный плейсхолдер "Select a date", чтобы изменить его надо править шаблон. Пример редактирования шаблона можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27727399/6766879)